# Best strategy for unit testing controller front to back in ASP.NET using DI

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, controller, castle

I'm new to DI and have a question about the best strategy for unit testing a controller.

I have a controller that uses DI to get the repository, mappingengine and logger. This is basically how i learned it from Kozmics sample application.

```
private readonly IRepository repository;
private readonly IMappingEngine mappingEngine;
private readonly ILogger logger;

public DossierController(IRepository repository, IMappingEngine mappingEngine, ILogger logger)
{
  this.repository = repository;
  this.mappingEngine = mappingEngine;
  this.logger = logger;
}
```

Now I have a method that is called to save a dossier. Inside the method the dossiermodel is mapped to a dossier and saved to the database.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Dossier")]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[AcceptParameter(Name = "button", Value = "save")]
public ActionResult Dossier_Save(string button, DossierModel dossierModel, string returnUrl)
{
  if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

  if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(dossierModel);

  Dossier dossier = mappingEngine.Map<DossierModel, Dossier>(dossierModel);
  dossier.DigitaleHandtekeningDatum = new DateTime(2011, 11, 11);

  repository.TransactionBegin();
  repository.Save(dossier);
  repository.TransactionCommit();

  return View();
}
```

I want to test the controller to make sure of two things: 1 that the dossier is correctly mapped and 2 that the dossier is actually completely persisted in the database.

Now my question is: what is the best strategy for this? Should I:

- Unit test the controller as a whole? And if so how?
- Mock the persistence? Then how do I test if the object is actually persisted?

Should this be done in a separate unittest specifically for testing the database persistence?

Answer (score 0):

First I think you probably want to use the [Authorize] attribute instead of testing Request.IsAuthenticated. It will remove the complexity of mocking the whole Request object.

I would then mock the repository, and test that the Save method is called with the right parameters (or not called, depending on the use case you are testing)

Comment: Request is not static in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Ah correct, but it's still hard to mock it. (havent worked with mvc for some time now, just remembered it was not straightforward to test). fixed my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would not unit test this. Take a look at the visualization of costs and benefits of unit testing at this blog: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/11/04/selective-unit-testing-costs-and-benefits/. I would argue that controllers typically have a high level of dependencies and a low level of complexity, just like a coordinator in the graph. Save your unit testing to the code that actually benefits from it, like algorithms, state machines, etc. You can integration test your controller logic using browser automation or you can use something like this http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/06/11/integration-testing-your-aspnet-mvc-application/ if you want to go in at the controller level.